# SmartGit change startup window preference

Tags: smartgit

I had to install SmartGit to a new device (Win11) and somehow this particular client always launches the Log Window on startup instead of the Working Tree Window as I am used to it from other devices. This drives me mad. I just cannot find a setting to change this behaviour.

I think there was a question regarding this during install, but reinstalling the client did not prompt it and I ended up in the same situation. So How can I change this to my preference (->show working tree window on launch).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the **Preferences**, section **User Interface** you can configure the default window.

Comment: How do you access Preferences ?

Comment: on a Mac, in version 22.1.4.  SmartGit > Settings... > User Interface : Then change the Startup Window option (Standard, Log Graph, or Working Tree).  You'll need to restart smartgit for the change to take effect.

Comment: For Windows, the Preferences section is available under the Edit tab.